# How to disable parsing code in script tags using JavaScript DOMParser?

Tags: javascript, domparser

I have the following text file with JavaScript tags:

```
<script>
...
</script>
<script>
...
</script>
<script>
...
</script>
```

when I parse it like so:

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(`<root>${data}</root>`, "text/xml");
const tags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

I get an error because there are < and > symbols in JS program code, like

```js
for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
```

I don't want to replace < > with &lt; &gt; because those are also present inside strings in the code.

Is it possible to disable parsing code inside script tags?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] that demonstrates the error

Comment: @Spectric it errors out when using `text/xml` to parse `<script>'<'</script>` since it is valid HTML but not valid XML

Comment: Well, you're trying to parse non-well-formed XML as XML. There will be errors. There is no per-tag configuration in `DOMParser`; indeed, there is no configuration at all beyond the MIME type passed to `parseFromString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing HTML, we use the mime type `text/html`

```js
const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
const tags = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the JS code in a [CDATA section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection)
so it looks like:

```
<script>
   <![CDATA[
      for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {....
  ]]>
</script>
```

These comments tell the xml parser to treat what is inside them as character data only